# Javascript Bookmarklet Duplicating URI / URL

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have the following bookmarklet:

```
javascript:findlink=document.getElementsByClassName(%22download_link%22)[2].href;window.open('https://myfiledrive.com/users/files/add?url='+findlink,'_blank');void(0);
```

Example:

```
<a class="download_link" href="example.com/pdf1.pdf">
<a class="download_link" href="example.com/pdf2.pdf">
<a class="download_link" href="example.com/pdf3.pdf">
```

Basically, it searches the currently active page, for the third iteration of an  tag with the class "download_link", and stores it in the variable "findink",

Then it loads 'https://myfiledrive.com/users/files/add?url='+findlink

In the above example it should load:

https://myfiledrive.com/users/files/add?url=example.com/pdf3.pdf

but what ends up happening is that this gets loaded:

https://myfiledrive.com/users/files/add?url=example.com/pdf3.pdf?url=example.com/pdf3.pdf

- so basically it's duplicating url=

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `url` param shouldn't be duplicated. You're not appending to `findlink` or anything. You can try the snippet below, it's exactly as you've posted.

Chrome will block the popup, but if you read the error message, there's no duplication going on:

> Blocked opening 'https://myfiledrive.com/users/files/add?url=https://stacksnippets.net/example.com/pdf3.pdf' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

`url` is only in there once no matter how many times I click.

```html
<a class="download_link" href="example.com/pdf1.pdf">1</a>
<a class="download_link" href="example.com/pdf2.pdf">2</a>
<a class="download_link" href="example.com/pdf3.pdf">3</a>

<a href="javascript:findlink=document.getElementsByClassName(%22download_link%22)[2].href;window.open('https://myfiledrive.com/users/files/add?url='+findlink,'_blank');void(0);">download</a>
```

Comment: Yeah. My only assumption is that the receiving URL is doing the duplicating.

Comment: The funny thing is, when I paste https://myfiledrive.com/users/files/add?url=example.com/pdf3.pdf in the address bar, no problems at all. But when loaded through the bookmarklet, that's when it causes the duplication. So confused.